# Divide dict of dicts into specific parts

Tags: python, dictionary

I have data format like this :

```
{0: {'offer_id': u'308249', 'affiliate_id': u'1014', 'approval_status': 'approved'}, 1: {'offer_id': u'308255', 'affiliate_id': u'1014', 'approval_status': 'approved'}, 2: {'offer_id': u'283063', 'affiliate_id': u'1014', 'approval_status': 'approved'}, 3: {'offer_id': u'313467', 'affiliate_id': u'1014', 'approval_status': 'approved'}, 4: {'offer_id': u'313673', 'affiliate_id': u'1014', 'approval_status': 'approved'}, 5: {'offer_id': u'324519', 'affiliate_id': u'1014', 'approval_status': 'approved'}, 6: {'offer_id': u'320501', 'affiliate_id': u'1014', 'approval_status': 'approved'}, 7: {'offer_id': u'320503', 'affiliate_id': u'1014', 'approval_status': 'approved'}, 8: {'offer_id': u'323593', 'affiliate_id': u'1014', 'approval_status': 'approved'}, 9: {'offer_id': u'323595', 'affiliate_id': u'1014', 'approval_status': 'approved'}, 10: {'offer_id': u'324441', 'affiliate_id': u'1014', 'approval_status': 'approved'}, 11: {'offer_id': u'324443', 'affiliate_id': u'1014', 'approval_status': 'approved'}, 12: {'offer_id': u'325129', 'affiliate_id': u'1014', 'approval_status': 'approved'}, 13: {'offer_id': u'325131', 'affiliate_id': u'1014', 'approval_status': 'approved'}, 14: {'offer_id': u'325133', 'affiliate_id': u'1014', 'approval_status': 'approved'}, 15: {'offer_id': u'325135', 'affiliate_id': u'1014', 'approval_status': 'approved'}}
```

I need to process only 10 dicts at a time so 
I need to divide this dict into parts such that each sub part **can have maximum 10 elements (key/value pairs)**.

API call I need to make can take maximum of 10 values in such format so I need to process parts by parts.

Example:

```
for data in data_in_chunks_of_10:
    api_call(data)
```

How do I achieve that efficiently?

Comment: What have you tried that was not efficient enough ?

Comment: Any requirements on how the keys should be distributed among the result dicts?

Comment: this question is very unclear to me.

Comment: is this homework?

Comment: If the keys are a contiguous range from `0` upwards, there's no reason not to use a `list`, which will in turn allow you to do slicing and speedy itertools recipes.

Comment: can you show the expected output or put some more details? The details aren't sufficient

Comment: Izaak data i will be sending requires this format. thats why I am using dict.

Comment: If you really needed to send it away like this, you could do `dict(enumerate(sensible_list_format))` before sending it off, after using the `list` functionality in your code.

Comment: Thanks @IzaakvanDongen This should work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a generator to return blocks of data as follows in your required block size:

```
def blocks(data, n=10):
    for i in xrange(0, len(data), n):
        yield data[i:i+n]

data = {
    0: {'offer_id': u'308249', 'affiliate_id': u'1014', 'approval_status': 'approved'}, 
    1: {'offer_id': u'308255', 'affiliate_id': u'1014', 'approval_status': 'approved'}, 
    2: {'offer_id': u'283063', 'affiliate_id': u'1014', 'approval_status': 'approved'}, 
    3: {'offer_id': u'313467', 'affiliate_id': u'1014', 'approval_status': 'approved'}, 
    4: {'offer_id': u'313673', 'affiliate_id': u'1014', 'approval_status': 'approved'}, 
    5: {'offer_id': u'324519', 'affiliate_id': u'1014', 'approval_status': 'approved'}, 
    6: {'offer_id': u'320501', 'affiliate_id': u'1014', 'approval_status': 'approved'}, 
    7: {'offer_id': u'320503', 'affiliate_id': u'1014', 'approval_status': 'approved'}, 
    8: {'offer_id': u'323593', 'affiliate_id': u'1014', 'approval_status': 'approved'}, 
    9: {'offer_id': u'323595', 'affiliate_id': u'1014', 'approval_status': 'approved'}, 
    10: {'offer_id': u'324441', 'affiliate_id': u'1014', 'approval_status': 'approved'}, 
    11: {'offer_id': u'324443', 'affiliate_id': u'1014', 'approval_status': 'approved'}, 
    12: {'offer_id': u'325129', 'affiliate_id': u'1014', 'approval_status': 'approved'}, 
    13: {'offer_id': u'325131', 'affiliate_id': u'1014', 'approval_status': 'approved'}, 
    14: {'offer_id': u'325133', 'affiliate_id': u'1014', 'approval_status': 'approved'}, 
    15: {'offer_id': u'325135', 'affiliate_id': u'1014', 'approval_status': 'approved'}}

for block in blocks(data.items(), 10):
    print block
```

This would give you two blocks of data as follows:

```
[(0, {'offer_id': u'308249', 'affiliate_id': u'1014', 'approval_status': 'approved'}), (1, {'offer_id': u'308255', 'affiliate_id': u'1014', 'approval_status': 'approved'}), (2, {'offer_id': u'283063', 'affiliate_id': u'1014', 'approval_status': 'approved'}), (3, {'offer_id': u'313467', 'affiliate_id': u'1014', 'approval_status': 'approved'}), (4, {'offer_id': u'313673', 'affiliate_id': u'1014', 'approval_status': 'approved'}), (5, {'offer_id': u'324519', 'affiliate_id': u'1014', 'approval_status': 'approved'}), (6, {'offer_id': u'320501', 'affiliate_id': u'1014', 'approval_status': 'approved'}), (7, {'offer_id': u'320503', 'affiliate_id': u'1014', 'approval_status': 'approved'}), (8, {'offer_id': u'323593', 'affiliate_id': u'1014', 'approval_status': 'approved'}), (9, {'offer_id': u'323595', 'affiliate_id': u'1014', 'approval_status': 'approved'})]
[(10, {'offer_id': u'324441', 'affiliate_id': u'1014', 'approval_status': 'approved'}), (11, {'offer_id': u'324443', 'affiliate_id': u'1014', 'approval_status': 'approved'}), (12, {'offer_id': u'325129', 'affiliate_id': u'1014', 'approval_status': 'approved'}), (13, {'offer_id': u'325131', 'affiliate_id': u'1014', 'approval_status': 'approved'}), (14, {'offer_id': u'325133', 'affiliate_id': u'1014', 'approval_status': 'approved'}), (15, {'offer_id': u'325135', 'affiliate_id': u'1014', 'approval_status': 'approved'})]
```